# Grid view on scroll call same web service with page increment

Tags: android, gridview, scroll

```
  rlDetail.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            if (dy > 0) //check for scroll down
            {
                visibleItemCount = mLayoutManager.getChildCount();
                VLogger.infoLog("visibleItemCount" + visibleItemCount + "");
                totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                VLogger.infoLog("totalItemCount" + totalItemCount + "");
                pastVisiblesItems =     mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                VLogger.infoLog("pastVisiblesItems" + pastVisiblesItems + "");

                if (loading) {
                    if ((visibleItemCount + pastVisiblesItems) >= totalItemCount) {
                        page_no = page_no + 1;
                        msgList();
                        VLogger.infoLog("...", "Last Item Wow !");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Grid view on scroll call same web service with page increment.how can i do like above in grid view in android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  girdview.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int scrollState) {
                // Pause fetcher to ensure smoother scrolling when flinging // You can ignore this part
                if (scrollState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_FLING) {
                    mImageFetcher.setPauseWork(true);
                } else {
                    mImageFetcher.setPauseWork(false);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

                final int _lastItem = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
                if (_lastItem > 0 && totalItemCount > 0)
                    if (_lastItem == albums.size() && !endOfAlbums && lastItem != _lastItem) {
                        lastItem = _lastItem;
                        // Last item is fully visible.
                        loadAlbums();
                    }
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    private void loadAlbums() {

        if (currentPage == 0) {
            albums.clear();
            endOfAlbums = false;
            lastItem = 0;
            // get new releases
            progressLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else
            progressLoadMore.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        if (Utility.isNetworkAvailable(getActivity())) {

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    // get the serverAlbums
                    ArrayList<Album> serverAlbums = ServerAPI.getAllAlbums(session.getLanguage(), currentPage);
                    if (serverAlbums.size() > 0)
                        albums.addAll(serverAlbums);
                    else
                        endOfAlbums = true;

                    currentPage++;

                    myHandler.post(updateRunnable);
                }
            }).start();
            updateRunnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    if (albums.size() > 0) {

                        imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        // get listview current position - used to maintain scroll position
                        int currentPosition = girdview.getFirstVisiblePosition();

                        // Setting new scroll position
                        girdview.smoothScrollToPosition(currentPosition + 1, 0);
                    } else
                        tvNoAlbums.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    progressLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    progressLoadMore.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            };
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.check_connectivity, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            progressLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            progressLoadMore.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    }
```

it's work for me try this